# How to horizontally distribute an array of objects in WPF?

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I want to list out an array of objects and have the items spread out evenly horizontally. If it wasn't a databound array I would just make a grid with the right number of columns and assign each item to a column. Problem is I don't know how to do that with a databound list control.

As a cheap alternative I have the items being listed horizontally using a stackpanel as the ItemsPanel for an ItemsControl like this:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ValveSettings}" Grid.Row="0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Row="0" />
                    <ScrollBar Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100000" Value="{Binding Path=DelayInMicroseconds}" SmallChange="100" LargeChange="1000" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DelayInMicroseconds}" Grid.Row="2" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Is there a way I can spread them out evenly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally spread list items apart with a margin on the ItemTemplate.  Put the margin on the non-starting side (i.e. if the list populates from the left, put the margin on the right).  In this way, each successive item will be placed x pixels from the previous item.

In your example above, I have added a margin to the Grid element.

```
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0 0 8 0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Row="0" />
                <ScrollBar Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100000" Value="{Binding Path=DelayInMicroseconds}" SmallChange="100" LargeChange="1000" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DelayInMicroseconds}" Grid.Row="2" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: How did you pick the margin of 8? Isn't this absolute value? If so wouldnt using an absolute value require tweaking depending on how many items are in the array and how large the window is?

Comment: Ahh, OK.  Yes, margin of 0 0 8 0 was arbitrary, as I thought you just wanted to have some space separating your items.  To cause Item containers to be positioned based on how many there are, you might see if there is a way to use a UniformGrid as your ItemsPanelTemplate.  I have not tried this, but I imagine you will need to constrain it to 1 row, and find some way of changing the number of columns to the number of items in the ItemsCollection.  I will see if I can test this in a while if you like.

Comment: Thank you, that is the heart of the problem I am trying to solve

Comment: This could be a separate answer, but @CodeWarrior pretty much got it in his comment (so you should accept his answer).   Basically, if you specify Rows="1" for the UniformGrid, and do not specify anything for Columns, it will just use as many columns as needed.  Of course, if you have too many items to fit in the visible space, you will want to wrap the whole ItemsControl in a ScrollViewer.

Comment: @WonkotheSane Great!  And good on you for the Hitchhikers reference in your name!  I was unsure of whether the UniformGrid would auto Column.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are right, uniform grid is the way to go. I initially dismissed it because he said I would need to change the number of columns on the fly, but if you just set Rows to "1" it works fine

Comment: Yeah, I initially did not know if the UniformGrid was smart enough to create columns like that.  Apparently it is.

Answer (score 3):

This is the results of the comments with CodeWarrior which works wonderfully:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Settings.Valves}" Grid.Row="0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Center" />
                    <ScrollBar Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100000" Value="{Binding Path=DelayInMicroseconds}" SmallChange="100" LargeChange="1000" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DelayInMicroseconds}" Grid.Row="2" TextAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```